# jquery data table how to populate on ajax request

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

Since my previous question was too confused I'm asking a new one.

I'm having this linq which I use to retrive data as json

```
var res = from c in model.Data 
          select new object[] { c.Id, c.Time, c.Number};
```

c.Time is DateTime object and Id and Number are integers.
Now, when this query is executed I'm getting same data repeated in number of model.Data counts. How can this query be rewriten to use foreach loop.

Comment: Where do you get the City and Country then?

Comment: @trailmax question is updated.

Answer (score 2):

you are creating an array of objects' array

Please use this:

```
var res = from c in model.Data 
          select new { ID=c.Id, Time=c.Time, Number=c.Number};
```

Then the variable will contain a List of objects with Properties ID, Time and Number.
This List will be easy to convert to JSON array of objects.